# Humans and color at night

Tags: visible-light, biophysics, vision

Why we can't see colors at night?

Comment: Because there is only one type of rod receptor, so that means we can only see in shades of gray. This is true?

Comment: Because my lecturer says it's not accurate.

Comment: pacman, I apologize, I was in a bad mood, but your own answer is correct

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a lack of research.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about human eyes not physics

Answer (score 2):

Because in the retina of human eyes there are light detector cells of two kinds: rods and cones.

Cones "see" colors but are not very good with low brightness. Rods don't detect colors but are better than rods in low brightness situations.

Thus at night cones don't function (they are for bright light) and we see only with rods which don't differentiate colors.

Answer (score -4):

With my understanding, any color except black will reflect light, and a black color will absorb light without reflecting back out. So, at night, there won't be enough light to shine on anything to have a reflection. Then, your eyes won't see anything

Comment: if you have no idea, why do you answer at all?